# the form refers to a form that does not exist

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I don't know if I haven't saved my form in a proper way, I opened my access today, it gives me a warning of "error accessing file. Network connection may have been lost." I didn't really understand what that meant but I went ahead to work on one of the files I was working on. But then I realized that when I click on "build event" it can't bring up the form code, the code I had yesterday was in "Form_Form1" and I tried to open that, it won't let me. Is there anyway I can rename one of them and try to relink them together. I tried to rename the Forms, it won't let me rename it back to Form 1

Thanks all. And Merry Christmas

Comment: Its better to use names that actually have some sort of meaning rather than just form1, form2...

Comment: Sounds like you had a table linked to an external spreadsheet or something.  Create a new database and go to External Data --> Access. Then select the messed up database and import the objects from it (except for the linked table).  You should then be able to open and work on them.

Comment: Thanks tlemaster, I have successfully exported my data base out, but is there anyway to recover the code I had in my messed up database. It won't let me open the old form 1 code file from access. I usually don't name them like that, I mean I don't name them like that, but somehow this code-form is named form1 but the form itself is not named form 1. :( so bad. why is this happeneing :(